# Using libxbee with MinGw and eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, mingw, xbee

I want to do some programming for Xbee, for this i have found a nice library namely the: libXbee. This library can be found here: [Link](http://code.google.com/p/libxbee/). But i can't find a way to use the library with MinGw and eclipse. Is there anyone how has used the libxbee library that can give me some pointers on how to do this? Or what is a good alternative? All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that's unfair - I offered you lots of pointers as to where to start with porting it, it already compiles and runs on Windows (using Microsoft's toolchain) and I even said I might be able to have a look at it *for you* this weekend!...

Comment: first of all thank you for even making the xbeelib! I think it is as great project! And if you have time to take a look at it then that would be great! I'm looki g forward to your reply!

Comment: Ps: indidn't have read your message on your google groups. Somehow i didn't get a notifecation. I have been working to get it to work for MingW for the past two days. But sofar with no result. If you would have time to take a look at it that would be great! I'm looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at my [ANSI C XBee Host Library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library) on GitHub instead, it includes more features and natively supports MinGW for the programs in `samples/win32`.  You can also use Cygwin for `samples/posix`, and it supports some embedded platforms as well.